# Как заставить ColorBox работать с представлениями?

Tags: drupal

Добрый день. На сайте Drupal 7 http://nevskylimo.ru/ требуется сделать, чтобы на главной странице картинки открывались в Колорбоксе. Главная страница представляет собой "вьюшку".

На страницах конкретных материалов (машин-лимузинов-автобусов) на которые можно попасть с главной - картинки в колорбоксе открываются без проблем т.к. у них есть атрибут data-colorbox-gallery="gallery-node-77-field_image". А вот у картинок которые во вьюшках собраны - у них этого атрибута нет. Видимо поэтому он не работает.

Аналогичная проблема на страницах, которые открываются из верхнего меню - т.к. открываются тоже вьюхи, а не материалы.

Как можно победить проблему и заставить Colorbox работать и на "представлениях"?

Comment: как у вас вюхи эти формируются? поля выводите или анонсы?

Comment: В том-то и дело, что выводятся анонсы. При попытке выводить поля (чтобы использовать некоторые хаки найденные в Сети) - полностью нарушается вёрстка и с этим возиться кажется будет сложнее, чем заставить картинки с анонсов открываться в Fancybox.

Я обратил внимание, что у тега "a" окруюжающего картинки с анонсов есть тот же класс "colorbox init-colorbox-processed cboxElement" - однако отсутствует характерный для открывающийся в боксе картинок атрибут data-colorbox-gallery="gallery-node-64-field_image" (значение типовое, оно разное бывает).

Comment: Попробовал добавить принудительно (jQuery в помощь) этот атрибут - ничего не изменилось, как не открывались картинки с анонсов в Colorbox, так и не открываются...

Comment: Тогда надо шаблон смотреть. Что и как там у вас выводиться. Код в вопрос добавьте.

Answer (score 1):

Поменять во views виджет картинки на Colorbox.

Comment: См. выше мои комментарии, у меня не поля во вьюхе используются - а "вывод анонсов". Переключение на режим полей рушит вёрстку напрочь.

Comment: Точно так же - в управлении отображением типа материала, для поля картинки поставить формат Colorbox.